# PHP | Вытянуть текст с input

Tags: php, html

Есть часть кода php и форма html. Вопрос состоит в следующем: Как вытянуть текст вписаный в input'e и записать его вместо "Название города" в php?

```
<?php $cityId = "Название города"; ?>




<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="city">Enter the name of a city.</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" aria-describedby="city" placeholder="E.g. New York, Tokyo">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Никак, невозможно просто так взять данные через JS и передать в файл PHP. Можете попробовать  взять информацию из инпута через JS записать в куки, а вот в PHP уже получить данну куку, однако, данная информация будет доступна после обновления страницы. В итоге вы пробуете сделать очень "нехороший" код )) советую почитать книги для минимального понятия работы PHP и Javascript

Answer (score 0):

пхп будет отрабатывать только после клика по кнопке "**Submit**"

```
<?php 
$cityId = "Название города"; 
if ($_GET && $_GET['city']){
    $cityId = $_GET['city'];
}
echo $cityId;

?>




<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="city">Enter the name of a city.</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" aria-describedby="city" placeholder="E.g. New York, Tokyo">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Если необходимо изменять значение во время печати в input, то стоит поработать с **ajax**